# In $S_3$, determine the set $T=\{ x\in S_3 | x^2=e\}$. Is $T$ a subgroup of $S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Here's my solution: Is it right or wrong?

$S_3=\{ \begin{cases} 1\mapsto1 \\ 2\mapsto 2 \\ 3\mapsto 3 \end{cases}, \begin{cases} 1\mapsto 2 \\ 2\mapsto 1 \\ 3\mapsto 3\end{cases}, \begin{cases} 1\mapsto 3 \\ 2 \mapsto 2 \\ 3\mapsto 1 \end{cases},\begin{cases} 1\mapsto 2 \\ 2\mapsto 3 \\ 3\mapsto 1 \end{cases}, \begin{cases} 1\mapsto3 \\ 2\mapsto1 \\ 3\mapsto2 \end{cases},\begin{cases} 1\mapsto3 \\ 2\mapsto2 \\ 3\mapsto1 \end{cases}\}$

$\Longrightarrow T=\{\begin{cases} 1\mapsto1 \\ 2\mapsto 2 \\ 3\mapsto 3 \end{cases}, \begin{cases} 1\mapsto 2 \\ 2\mapsto 1 \\ 3\mapsto 3\end{cases}, \begin{cases} 1\mapsto 3 \\ 2 \mapsto 2 \\ 3\mapsto 1 \end{cases}\}$

We have the identity element: $e=\begin{cases} 1\mapsto1 \\ 2\mapsto 2 \\ 3\mapsto 3 \end{cases}.$ And every element has a unique inverse, since $\forall x\in T; x^2=e$ (the inverses are themselves). Therefore, I think $T$ has to be a subgroup of $S_3$.

**Anything wrong** with the proof, please?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A couple of problems. First, you missed one element of $T$ (note that the third and sixth elements of your list of $S_3$ are the same). Second, if you compose the second and third elements of $T$, do you get another element of $T$?

Answer (score 0):

You have to show it is closed under the group operation, so that it will form a binary operation on the subset. (The associative law follows directly from that on the group)

Answer (score 0):

1. What about 
   $$\begin{cases} 1\mapsto1 \\ 2\mapsto 3 \\ 3\mapsto 2\end{cases}
   $$? Also, remember that the order of $S_n$ is $n!$.
2. Compute $$\begin{cases} 1\mapsto2 \\ 2\mapsto 1 \\ 3\mapsto 3\end{cases}
   \times 
   \begin{cases} 1\mapsto3 \\ 2\mapsto 2 \\ 3\mapsto 1\end{cases}
   $$
   Is it an element of $T$?